Promise is returning [object Promise] when using replace method in javascript
I tried below code where inside replace method fetch api call is happening and it returning response and based on response returning <img>. But issue is its returning [object Promise]
 str.replace(/!([^|!]*(?:jpe?g|png|gif|mp4|mp3|mkv|mov))(?:\|width=(\d*\.?\d+%?)(?:,height=(\d*\.?\d+%?))?)?!/gm,  async (match, capture) => {
                let m, reg = /!([^|!]*(?:jpe?g|png|gif|mp4|mp3|mkv|mov))(?:\|width=(\d*\.?\d+%?)(?:,height=(\d*\.?\d+%?))?)?!/gm;
                let imageConfig = [];
                while ((m = reg.exec(str)) !== null) {
                    imageConfig.push({ file: m[1], width: (m[2] || ''), height: (m[3] || '') });
                }
                let payload = {
                    'columns': [
                        {
                            'id': columnMeta.id,
                            'values': [
                                { "type": "@thumbnail", "values": imageConfig.map(e => e?.file) },
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
                payload.rowId = rowData?.id;
                let reolvedFile = [];
                let response = await Service.post(
                    generateAPIURL({
                        boardId: TableHelper.getwrapperConfig?.boardId,
                        tableId: TableHelper.getwrapperConfig?.tableId,
                        columnId: columnMeta?.id,
                        type: "getresolvedValue",
                    }),
                    null,
                    JSON.stringify({ ...payload })
                )
                let values = response?.columns?.[0]?.values;
                imageConfig.map(e => e?.file)?.map(o => {
                    let index = values?.findIndex(e => e?.name === o);
                    if (index !== -1) {
                        reolvedFile.push(values[index]);
                    }
                })
                
                //Find the matching entry
                var info = reolvedFile?.find(({ name }) => name === capture);
                let width = imageConfig.find((e) => e?.file === capture)?.width || 200;
                let height = imageConfig.find((e) => e?.file === capture)?.height || 200;
                return info ?
                    `<img src="${info?.thumbnail}"   data-name="${info?.name}"  width=${width} height=${height} style="width:'${width}px';height:'${height}px';display: inline-block;"/>`
                    : `<div  id="${capture}" data-name="${capture}" class="linear-background" style="width:'${width}px';height:'${height}px';display: inline-block;" ></div>`;
            })

I tried above code and expecting it should return <img> after response comes instead of [object Promise]
return info 
    ? `<img src="${info?.thumbnail}"   data-name="${info?.name}"  width=${width} height=${height} style="width:'${width}px';height:'${height}px';display: inline-block;"/>`
    : `<div  id="${capture}" data-name="${capture}" class="linear-background" style="width:'${width}px';height:'${height}px';display: inline-block;" ></div>`;


String#replace has no provision to await for a replacer function's returned promise to finish – and you are returning a promise, since the replacer is async.

Ok. Can you please guide how to fix this.

Whenever you see [object Object] or similar it means you've attempted to convert an object to a string and that object does not have a method to convert to a string.

The capture from the regex match hasn't been used before the await API call. You do not want to call an API in a string substitution function that it may cause a serious waste of network resources.
Consider moving all irrelevent statements including await calls outside of replace function scope.
How the structure could be changed based on your code:
async function main() {
    /* move all irrelevent statements outside of replace function -- START */
    let m, reg = /!([^|!]*(?:jpe?g|png|gif|mp4|mp3|mkv|mov))(?:\|width=(\d*\.?\d+%?)(?:,height=(\d*\.?\d+%?))?)?!/gm;
    let imageConfig = [];
    while ((m = reg.exec(str)) !== null) {
        imageConfig.push({ file: m[1], width: (m[2] || ''), height: (m[3] || '') });
    }
    let payload = {
        'columns': [
            {
                'id': columnMeta.id,
                'values': [
                    { "type": "@thumbnail", "values": imageConfig.map(e => e?.file) },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    payload.rowId = rowData?.id;
    let reolvedFile = [];
    let response = await Service.post(
        generateAPIURL({
            boardId: TableHelper.getwrapperConfig?.boardId,
            tableId: TableHelper.getwrapperConfig?.tableId,
            columnId: columnMeta?.id,
            type: "getresolvedValue",
        }),
        null,
        JSON.stringify({ ...payload })
    )

    let values = response?.columns?.[0]?.values;

    imageConfig.map(e => e?.file)?.map(o => {
        let index = values?.findIndex(e => e?.name === o);
        if (index !== -1) {
            reolvedFile.push(values[index]);
        }
    });
    /* move all irrelevent statements outside of replace function -- END */

    return str.replace(reg, (match, capture) => {
        //Find the matching entry
        var info = reolvedFile?.find(({ name }) => name === capture);
        let width = imageConfig.find((e) => e?.file === capture)?.width || 200;
        let height = imageConfig.find((e) => e?.file === capture)?.height || 200;
        return info ?
            `<img src="${info?.thumbnail}"   data-name="${info?.name}"  width=${width} height=${height} style="width:'${width}px';height:'${height}px';display: inline-block;"/>`
            : `<div  id="${capture}" data-name="${capture}" class="linear-background" style="width:'${width}px';height:'${height}px';display: inline-block;" ></div>`;
    })
}

main();


"You do not want to call an API in a string substitution function that it may cause a serious waste of network resources." Can you maybe elaborate on this, especially in the light of what your answer is doing?

@AKX A string substitution function may be called from 0 to millions of times for different input strings. Calling an API of matching count times simultaneously might not be the best idea. Ideally a substitution function should be pure of only string manipulations.

Right, rate limiting promise-powered work is a different question altogether (and there are easy libraries such as p-limit and p-queue to do just that). However, for OP's case, where they need to fetch something for all occurrences of their pattern in the input, they really do need to call the API for each occurrence.

@AKX But for OP’s case, the API call did not use any of the reference from the matching part capture. Which means the API calling part can be safely separated from the substitution - it only needs to be called once.

TBH, I think there's a bug in OP's implementation (aside from the obvious promise stuff) in that it's doing matching with the same pattern in a loop within the replacer function... Sure, if the API OP is using supports batching (IOW we'd want to find all matches first, gather the IDs or whatever and resolve them in a single remote call), the case is slightly different.

String#replace has no provision to await for a replacer function's returned promise to finish – and you are returning a promise, since the replacer is async.
You'll need something that can deal with this, e.g.


async function asyncStringReplace(string, pattern, replacer) {
  
  const promises = [];
  // Find all replacements once (discarding the result),
  // but keeping track of the promises that will eventually
  // resolve to the replacement values
  string.replace(pattern, (match, ...args) => {
    promises.push(replacer(match, ...args));
  });
  // Await for all of the gathered promises to resolve
  const replacements = await Promise.all(promises);
  // Run the replacement again, draining the replacements array
  return string.replace(pattern, () => replacements.shift());
}

async function fetchResultForMatch(m) {
  // pretend we'd fetch something from the network
  return m.toUpperCase() + "!";
}

async function main() {
  const string = "hello world, all words longer than five letters in this text should be screamy";
  const result = await asyncStringReplace(string, /\w{5,}/g, fetchResultForMatch);
  console.log(result);
}

main();




Can you please show this in my piece of code.

For your example: replace str.replace(blah, bleh) with await asyncStringReplace(str, blah, bleh)
